# Sql Query Data Reader Returning True even it's False in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Good day!

It's taking me hours why my query returns a true even it's false.

Here's my code.

```
public SqlDataReader Check(BEL bel) {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Total) as OverallTotal FROM table WHERE Id=@Id AND DateFrom=@From AND DateTo=@To AND Status='Without'";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",bel.CLEmpID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", bel.CLPayrollFrom);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", bel.CLPayrollTo);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return dr;
    }
```

Suppose the parameterized values are:

```
@Id = 0001
@From = 1/28/2016
@To = 1/29/2016
```

Here's my method calling the datareader

```
SqlDataReader drCheck;

drCheck = bal.Check(bel);
if (drCheck.HasRows == true)
{
    drCheck.Read();
    // I'm inside the computation of OverallTotal
}else{
    drCheck.Close();
   // I'm out
}
drCheck.Close();
```

The problem is, when the value of my "To", for instance, is 1/30/2016, it suppose to go to the false which is out of the true condition but it is not.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the reader has no rows you are closing it twice

Comment: It doesn't matter for  now. The problem is, why even the query is false, it still sending me inside the if == true

Comment: Why do you need the else part ? The query always returns a result. You don't even need `SqlDataReader `. Use `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: Use `ExecuteScalar` and check returned value for `NULL`.

Comment: I don't understand. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't need a Reader, you can use ExecuteScalar:

```
public decimal? Check(BEL bel)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = dbcon.getcon();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Total) as OverallTotal FROM table WHERE Id=@Id " + 
                      "AND DateFrom=@From AND DateTo=@To AND Status='Without'";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", bel.CLEmpID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", bel.CLPayrollFrom);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", bel.CLPayrollTo);

    object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    decimal? value = null;
    if (obj != DBNull.Value)
        value = Convert.ToDecimal(obj);

    return value;
}

decimal? total = bal.Check(bel);
if (total.HasValue)
{
    // do something with the total.Value
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: It still sending me to the // I'm in part. :(

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. It still sending me to the if(drCheck.Read()).

Comment: @mark That's exactly where it should go because there are results. Check the edit you don't even need to use a reader, you `ExecuteScalar`

Comment: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object', Operator != cannot be applied to operand of type 'System.data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' and 'int'

Comment: @mark i changed the method to return decimal but you didn't. Just use the same code above.

Comment: Ah I missed () hehe in the ExecuteScalar :) ahm one last error here. "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an express of type 'decimal' in the var total line

Comment: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an express of type 'decimal' in the var total line

Comment: Additional information: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. in the return Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) when the choose different "To" value from 1/29/2016 to 1/30/2016 :(

Comment: @mark check the final edit. Everything should work fine now.

Comment: Man another error in building the code. It says here "Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal?' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: the "value" is highlighted when I click the error below the error list.

Comment: @mark man you need to change the return type of the method to decimal? and not decimal.

Comment: @mark `public decimal? Check(BEL bel)` instead of `public decimal Check(BEL bel)`

Comment: object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            decimal value = 0;
            if (obj != DBNull.Value)
                value = Convert.ToDecimal(obj);

            return value;

Comment: I made something like that. :) My method is still public decimal and I removed the ? in the decimal? value = null and put the value = 0;

Comment: Thank you man! :) I've learned new things today :) ExecuteScalar stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your query, you are have aggregate function.  Whether your from & to returns no rows, as you have aggregate function, you always get one row with value at least zero.

Comment: What do you think should I need to do to tell the data reader to send the false query into the else condition? :/

Comment: @Barani,  sum of empty set will retun NULL not zero.

Comment: Yes, when I changed my To = 1/30/2016, it says, Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: SELECT isnull(SUM(Total), 0) as OverallTotal FROM table WHERE Id=@Id AND DateFrom=@From AND DateTo=@To AND Status='Without' having isnull(sum(Total), 0) > 0"

Answer (score 1):

Your query always returns a value even if there are no matching records because you are summing them, so you get `NULL`in case of no records and in the case of all matching records' values are `NULL`. You'll get 0 if there are records and the sum-result is 0(including `NULL` values which will be counted as 0).

You could use following approach that uses a different query to return both informations:

```
public bool GetOverAll(int id, DateTime payrollFrom, DateTime payrollTo, out double? overall)
{
    overall = null;
    string sql = @"
    ;WITH Data AS(
        SELECT t.*
        FROM table 
        WHERE Id     = @Id 
        AND DateFrom = @From 
        AND DateTo   = @To 
        AND Status   = 'Without'
    )
    SELECT HasRows = CAST(CASE WHEN EXIST( SELECT 1 FROM CTE )
                          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit),
           OverallTotal = SUM(Total)
    FROM CTE";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", payrollFrom);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", payrollTo);
        con.Open();
        using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rd.Read())
            {
                bool hasRows = rd.GetBoolean(0);
                if (!rd.IsDBNull(1))
                    overall = rd.GetDouble(1);
                return hasRows;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("This should never be the case!");
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

You now know if there were matching records or not:

```
double? overall;
bool hasRows = GetOverAll(id, payrollFrom, payrollTo, out overall); 
if(hasRows && overall.HasValue)
{
   // matching records and the sum of these values was not NULL (possible if nullable column and all values were NULL)
   double total = overall.Value;
}
```

Comment: Not 0 but NULL in case of no records. And may be NULL too otherwise, if the column is nullable.

Comment: And if all the selected rows have NULL then ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at simple example

```
SELECT SUM(total1) as tt1, SUM(total2) AS tt2, COUNT(*) AS [Nbr of rows]
FROM (
    SELECT 10 AS total1, CAST(NULL AS INT) total2 -- 
    ) t
--WHERE 1=2
```

Generally when the SUMmed column  is nullable only COUNT(*) will tell the difference are there any rows selected or no rows selected.

Comment: I'm using ExecuteScalar now, from one of the persons who answered here. The problem is when the value OverallTotal is 0 so, it must go to the false but I got this error "Additional information: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. in the return Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) when the choose different "To" value from 1/29/2016 to 1/30/2016 :("

Comment: So, even the value is 0, it still sending me to the if != 0 condition.

Comment: You need to decide, from business point of view, are those cases (no rows, some rows returning NULL, some rows returning 0) the same or should be treated differently. In last case you need DataReader, otherwise ExecuteScalar is enough.

Comment: I had a problem in Data reader, so I go for ExecuteScalar for now. Thanks for the tip :)